# Parsing 64-bit unsigned integer on iOS

Tags: cocoa-touch, parsing, ios, unsigned-long-long-int

I have very big unsigned integral number in NSString. This may be big to 2^64.
Is there an existing functions/classes parsing this?

As I know, it's unsigned long long value, but, It's hard to know what kind of method should I use to parse this.

Comment: what exactly you mean by parsing? the conversion from your NSString number to unsigned long long?

Comment: To request support for reading unsigned values from NSString, please visit http://bugreport.apple.com and file a dupe of radar://2264733 against component `Foundation | X`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps not the prettiest answer, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
unsigned long long parsedValue = strtoull([yourString UTF8String], NULL, 0);
```

Someone else might have a more cocoa-ey way of doing it.

Comment: Oh, this is nice. I like C functions. Thanks for answer!

Comment: Just [yourString longLongValue];

Comment: @roman truba: that works for signed values up to 2^63; the questioner wanted *unsigned* values up to 2^64.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old one but here's a slightly more Cocoa-ey variant of Stephen Canon's (correct) answer:

```
#import <stdlib.h>

@implementation NSString (MyHelpers)
    - (unsigned long long)unsignedLongLongValue {
        return strtoull([self UTF8String], NULL, 0);
    }
@end
```

Now all strings will respond to the unsignedLongLongValue selector.

Answer (score 0):

This might work, though it only gets to [2^63 - 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29):

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:numericString];
long long valueFromString;
if(![scanner scanLongLong:&valueFromString]) {
    //ERROR
}
```

There doesn't appear to be a scanUnsignedLongLong method for NSScanner.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but that's just the trouble what I'd explained. The problem is just the value can be up to 2^64.